# Create Custom Validation Errors using en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model that does not extend Active Record Base.  I want to be able to change the names of my attributes so that they aren't just the variable names.  For example one of my variables is "bookNum" but when it is displayed in an error I want it to be "Book Number"

My current en.yml is

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"

  errors:
    format: "%{message}"

  library:
    attributes:
      bookNum: "Book Number"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
en:

    attributes:
        bookNum: "Book Number"
```

you don't need the model name

Comment: how about if available same attribute in different models and I want use different translation?

Comment: You can scope it like this: (Rails 3.2) `en.activerecord.attributes.library.bookNum`

Comment: @MrYoshiji as in my answer?

Comment: but what if the model isnt an activerecord

Comment: @CamSonaris yes, I just asked about it, so if I use your answer and I have same attribute in different models with different translation not work, I should using MrYoshiji says. Thanks